# r - Getting start and end date of any year,quarters or months given as input

Tags: r, date, lubridate

For a given period be it Quarter,Month or year how to get the  Start and End Date .

Examples:

```
Input : c("Q1","2020)  
Expected Output:  2020-01-01 - 2020-03-31 

Input : c(11,12,2019)
Expected Output:   2019-11-01 - 2019-11-31
```

I have tried Package timeperiodsR and it gives the exact output but input it expects to be date .

Code : this_month(x = "2019-01-01")

Output : Time period: 2019-01-01 (Tuesday) - 2019-01-31 (Thursday)

timeperiodsR expects input should be a date eg.  x = "2019-01-01" . But our input will be like x=  c("01","2019) (month ,year) or (quarter,year) . How to get expected output with this input.

Comment: please try to provide a specific sample code you are dealing with, so we can understand better the issue and reproduce it. Provide the source code and the result as well as the expected result.

Comment: Please provide a reprex. Its hard to understand your question.

Comment: Please be more specific with what your requirements are. The lubridate package is your friend for all date/time things - the as.yearqtr function from zoo might also help with input as quarters.

Comment: if a user gives quarter and year as input how to get its corresponding date range                For eg. Input ("Q1","2020)  , Output should be  2020-01-01 - 2020-03-31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to check the R package [`zoo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html):

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

# year
input <- c("2010", "2015", "2019", "2020")
as.Date(paste0(input, "-01-01")) # start date
#> [1] "2010-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01"
as.Date(paste0(input, "-12-31")) # end data
#> [1] "2010-12-31" "2015-12-31" "2019-12-31" "2020-12-31"

# month
input <- c("2010-01", "2015-05", "2019-09", "2020-12")
input_month <- as.yearmon(input)
as.Date(input_month) # start date
#> [1] "2010-01-01" "2015-05-01" "2019-09-01" "2020-12-01"
as.Date(input_month, frac = 1) # end date
#> [1] "2010-01-31" "2015-05-31" "2019-09-30" "2020-12-31"

# quarter
input <- c("2010 Q4", "2015 Q2", "2019 Q3", "2020 Q1")
input_qrt <- as.yearqtr(input) # transform into yearqrt objects
as.Date(input_qrt) # start date
#> [1] "2010-10-01" "2015-04-01" "2019-07-01" "2020-01-01"
as.Date(input_qrt, frac = 1)
#> [1] "2010-12-31" "2015-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2020-03-31"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Check the help page of `?zoo::as.yearmon` and `?zoo::as.yearqrt` to understand the last two cases.

Comment: If I answered all your question you should accept this answer!